# Parse HTML with only a single td multiple a, in python (or in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am not good at beautifulsoup so i tried using pandas read_html. It kinda works but the problem is it just concatenates by elements

url: http://shakespeare.mit.edu/index.html

my code:

```
url='http://shakespeare.mit.edu/index.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
```

Thank you

Comment: What do u mean by concatenates by elements ?

Comment: You can get the data frame with `dfs[1]`, but it is not `pd.read_html` but `beautifulsoup' because it is bundled in one line.

Comment: @r-beginners when I do dfs[1] it returns 1 row with all the elements. (each title is concatenated with each other and not separated as lists)